# Как в choices.js из выпадающего списка убрать выбранный элемент

Tags: javascript

В данном списке выбран элемент "Анна Васильева", как убрать этот элемент из выпадающего списка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: choiceList.passedElement.triggerEvent('removeItem', {id: 1, value: 'Анна Васильева', programmatic: true})

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.is-selected {
  display: none;
}
```